# Gitlab-ci: pushing a repo from Gitlab to the Gitlab Runner host?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab-ci to deploy some Docker stack files on a couple of remote servers. It works great to build the image, push to the registry, and then pull and deploy.

However, I am somehow getting stuck with a much simpler use case - I just want to have my repository on gitlab to be pushed to a folder on the remote server. Currently, I have a cron job doing a git pull every 5 minutes, but I would rather have this in a gitlab-ci file so I can eventually add some tests, etc.

Here is my current attempt. I have tried a bunch of variations at this point though.

```
 deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - apk update && apk add git
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - if [ ! -d .git ] ; then git clone ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL} . ; else echo "Respository already cloned" ; fi
    - git remote set-url origin ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}
    - git pull origin ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    - git reset --hard ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - git submodule init
    - git submodule update
    - git reset --hard --recurse-submodule HEAD
    - git clean -f
    - git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -f
    - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR ; echo
```

And my config:

```
 [[runners]]
  name = "Docker Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = ""
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",
               "/mnt/airflow/dags:/builds",
               "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

My code is being added in the /mnt/airflow/dags directory on the host, but it has a few subfolders I want to get rid of (the full path is /dags/runner_id/0/project_name/project). My goal is to just have the path be /mnt/airflow/dags/project.

I tried using a Shell executor as well, but since my gitlab Runner is a docker container, it was just adding the data inside the container and I did not see an example of mounting a volume to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled shared runners and registered a gitlab-runner (docker image, docker executor). I edited the toml file and mounted a volume from my host machine to the $TARGET_DIR below. Works exactly as I wanted

```
stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  TARGET_DIR: /home/gitlab-runner/$CI_PROJECT_NAME

deploy_airflow:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - apk update && apk add rsync
    - mkdir -pv $TARGET_DIR
    - rsync -a --delete ./ $TARGET_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for easy (file based) deployment using a *gitlab-runner*

#### Local Runner

You already mentioned this yourself. Have a *gitlab-runner* on the target host using the shell executor and then simply copy the files to the target directory. It can be a bit tricky to properly set the permissions but apart from that it is very straightforward.

If you can only run the runner inside a container, you could still use this approach by bind-mounting the target directory of the deployment into the runner's container

#### Deploy with SSH

For this to work, the gitlab server must be able to reach the deployment host via SSH.

1. Create a deployment user on the target machine
2. Add an authorized SSH key to that user
3. Add the private key of that SSH key as a variable to your gitlab repository
4. Use the key to run a scp/rsync operation from the runner to the deploy host

The script for that could look something like that:

```
 before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get --yes install openssh-client rsync
    # Add host key of webserver to known hosts file
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "|1|NBu3XQDeVt3ea6yoK55GC8esO4w=|Jn7zY5dvsrGno2yxK5EzZNyRJSI= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBGaaaexlUD2C8fbxfUUv6651J+Dc+KXYZHlM+INppRmefRwNyAsmEQO2YobNpisleXqeJeapUyQuu0GIwhKNzrM=" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
  script:
    - rsync -az --delete --omit-dir-times . gitdeploy@web.my:/var/www/www.my.site/
```

Comment: thank  you - I have tried both of these methods so I am confident that I have some minor dumb mistake causing it to fail. Using SSH, can I do this from the container running gitlab runner? I can't find the IP address or domain name (but this is an Azure instance behind the corporate network - I am unable to interact with it outside VPN).

Comment: And regarding the shell executor from the container, mounting the volume did work. Is there a way to alter the path though? I do not want /{runner_id}/0/project_name/project - it would be best to just create a folder called project inside the mounted directory. Surely there must be a simple way to do this? It would completely satisfy my requirement. I am pulling a bunch of projects into a single folder on the host machine (Airflow DAGs folder)

Comment: Ad SSH: As I wrote, the runner must be able to reach the deployment host via SSH. It beeing a container is not a problem. If you need a VPN connection for that, you need to add those credentials and the setup to the *before_script*, too.
Ad mount: Bind mounting is a docker feature that is independent of gitlab-runner. Just pass a poarameter like `--volume /host/directory:/container/director` to your *docker run* command. The paths can be chosen as you like them. */host/directory* could be */var/www* for instance.